# Binary Tree Traversal - Preorder, Inorder, Postorder

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the following output

```
Preorder : 50 5 20 15 27 42 35 25 55 70 60 80 95 90 75
Inorder  : 5 15 20 25 27 35 42 50 55 60 70 75 80 90 95
Postorder: 5 20 15 27 42 35 25 55 70 60 80 95 90 75 50
```

Instead I am getting this

```
Preorder : 136161285312597531284813109128551336214133138721362114128146401438414645
Inorder  : 531259712848128531285513109133621361613621138721412814133143841464014645
Postorder: 531284812597128551336213109128531362114128138721438414645146401413313616
```

Here is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

//Preorder Funcation
void Preorder(struct Node *root) {

    if (root == NULL) return; // if tree/sub-tree is empty, return and exit

    cout << root->data;         // Visit
    Preorder(root->left);     // Move left
    Preorder(root->right);    // move right
}

//Inorder Funcation
void Inorder(Node *root) {
    if (root == NULL) return; // if tree/sub-tree is empty, return and exit

    Inorder(root->left);       //Move left
    cout << root->data;         //Visit
    Inorder(root->right);      // move right
}

//Postorder Funcation
void Postorder(Node *root) {
    if (root == NULL) return; // if tree/sub-tree is empty, return and exit

    Postorder(root->left);    // Move left
    Postorder(root->right);   // move right
    cout << root->data;         // Visit
}

// Function to Insert Node in a Binary Search Tree
Node* Insert(Node *root, int data) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = new Node();
        root->data = data;
        root->left = root->right = NULL;
    }
    else if (data <= root->data)
        root->left = Insert(root->left, data);
    else
        root->right = Insert(root->right, data);
    return root;
}

int main() {

    Node *root = NULL;
    root = Insert(root, '50');
    root = Insert(root, '75');
    root = Insert(root, '25');
    root = Insert(root, '15');
    root = Insert(root, '60');
    root = Insert(root, '35');
    root = Insert(root, '90');
    root = Insert(root, '42');
    root = Insert(root, '20');
    root = Insert(root, '27');
    root = Insert(root, '5');
    root = Insert(root, '55');
    root = Insert(root, '95');
    root = Insert(root, '80');
    root = Insert(root, '70');


    cout << "Preorder: ";   //Diaplay Nodes in Preorder. 
    Preorder(root);
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Inorder: ";    //Display Nodes in Inorder
    Inorder(root);
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Postorder: ";  //Display Nodes in Postorder
    Postorder(root);
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger?

Comment: Also if your problem is with pre-order, why post for the other orders? That code is not relevant

Comment: Also, why not try a simple tree, maybe 4 or 5 nodes, so that you can get a better sense of the flow of the code and identify what's wrong?  If your traversal fails with 4 or 5 nodes, it isn't going to work with 15 nodes.

Comment: Remove the single-quotes from your `int` literals. For example, it should be 50 instead of '50'. The quotes make multi-character literals, not what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Removing the single quotes worked.

Comment: Why is "harshini" != 'TJ Manning" - i.e. name on last comment compared with the poster?

Comment: I updated my profile between the time I posted and comment.

Comment: Just curious why you started off TJ Manning and then ended up with Harshini

Comment: I was just in a hurry to setup my profile, and Harshini is the profile name that I like to use.

Comment: @Harshini *Removing the single quotes worked.* -- So this indicates you never really tested your `Insert()` function at all and just assumed it worked.  Even inserting the first value would have shown something weird is going on in the `data` part of the Node.